# Pycharm is throwing me errors in my Django project for something that works

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am getting errors for this

```
from posts import views
```

even though it works. "posts" and "views"
have red lines under them but it works. Even though it may seem minor to some it throws me off sometimes being that I'm fairly new to the framework. How Can I make this go away?

Comment: Do these modules have the __ init __.py (no spaces, but stack overflow formats the text if I remove them) file inside them, so that python (and pycharm) understand they're in fact modules?

Comment: @LucaBezerra yes, they are generated automatically

Comment: Worth checking your settings to make sure that your PYTHONPATH and current working directory are what you expect; PyCharm will save it's own settings that override your default environment's.

Comment: try marking the parent dir (in which the `posts` dir exist) as `Sources Root`